# Is there a way to use the over function in r to retrieve all polygons that do NOT have points in them?

Tags: r, overlay

I have used the over function to retrieve the polygons of a map that contain points. I'am wondering, for my own learning purposes, if there is a way to use the over function to retrieve the polygons that don't have points in them. Is this possible?

Here is some code to return polygons of a map WITH points in them:

```
coordinates(data) <- ~ long_xcord + lat_ycord

# Set the projection of the SpatialPointsDataFrame using the projection of the shapefile.
proj4string(data) <- proj4string(shapeData)

p <- over(data, shapeData, returnList = TRUE)

p <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, p)
```

can the above be modified to return the polygons that DO NOT have points in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the results of your over query to select from the original polygon layer, and its easier if you just set returnList to False to get a dataframe e.g.

```
p <- over(points, polys)
polys_notint <- polys[!(polys$id_field %in% unlist(p$id_field)), ]
```